# PHP Mail function with Multi language

Tags: php, email, mime

I am unable to send emails in some languages. I tried adding content-type with UTF-8. Asi tried encoding the `$body = utf8_encode($_POST['sendmessage'];` but it still doesn't work.

When I try sending

```
Meu nome é Rick
```

Email is being sent as

```
Meu nome Ã© Rick
```

**My code is**

```
        $from = "xxxxx <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>";
        $to = $_POST['sendname']."<".$_POST['sendemail'].">";
        $subject = $_POST['sendsubject'];
        $body = $_POST['sendmessage'];
        $host = "pro.turbo-smtp.com";
        $username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        $password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        $headers = array ('Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Date' => date("r"),
        'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => 587,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));
        $crlf = "\r\n";
        $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);    
        $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
        $bodyx = $mime->get();
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $bodyx);
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: You’re not using PHPMailer. Looks like Pear’s Mail MIME package or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small error in your header

```
'Content-Type' => 'text/html: charset=UTF-8'
```

should be

```
'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

with semi-colon `;` as separator.

Also, try using a tried and tested package like **PHPMailer** for sending the mails. They will take care of nuances like the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks, still having the same problem after adding a semi-colon, worst case if I can't find I will switch to PHPMailer.

Comment: Could you try updating the mime 
`$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);    
$mime->setHTMLBody($body);
$mime->setTXTBody(html_entity_decode($body, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); // add this`

Comment: Still no luck, I finally changed the library and fixed the issue.  Thanks